Class clojure.lang.Reflector Android Studio
I need help in this problem, i'm newby in this themes.
Cause: class clojure.lang.Reflector cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @4d6036ae

Thank's
I have android studio 2023.1.1, it's a old app, i try update Android Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version and not working for me.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31

i dont know if necessary more information
